# Как задать минимальный приоритет sql запросу?

Tags: sql, sql-server, запрос

Как данному запросу задать минимальный приоритет выполнения? На самом деле запрос значительно больше.. Используется MS SQL Server 2014. Впервые сталкиваюсь с приоритетами, поэтому прошу сильно не запинывать)

```
SELECT * FROM users
```

Comment: А какой смысл такому простому запросу что то делать с приоритетами. И такие средства (если они вообще есть) зависят от конкретной СУБД. А вот СУБД вы в вопросе не указали. Так же это может зависеть от клиента, сам запрос же быстро вернет первые записи, а от того как клиент будет читать продолжение так же зависит нагрузка на БД. И клиента вы так же не указали ...

Comment: Спасибо за замечания! Поправил в вопросе. Мне главное понять как он (приоритет) задается к конкретному запросу. БД будет стремительно расти,  предполагается более 1млн. записей

Comment: А зачем запросу надо выставлять приоритет ? Ему (запросу) действительно надо перебирать одновременно миллион записей ? Правильно построенные индексы и некоторая денормализация БД обычно решают все проблемы в производительности. И вообще для СУБД лучше что бы запрос завершился как можно быстрее, потому что он своим существованием может блокировать работу других запросов, а следовательно снижение приоритета может ухудшить общую ситуацию. А вообще в sql-server нет даже такого понятия как приоритет. Есть управление ресурсами по пользователям, но это другая тема и вряд ли даст то что вы ожидаете

Comment: В Enterprise Edition есть регулятор ресурсов (т.н. _resource governor_), кот. позволяет входящие соединения направлять (по какому-то признаку) в разные группы рабочей нагрузки (но не конкретный запрос, а _все_ запросы данного соединения). Такую группу можно создать и поместить в пул с ограничениями по cpu, memory, iops (также группе можно установить `importance = low`).

Comment: Не в Enterprise можно попробовать "задавить" конкретный запрос подсказками `MAXDOP`, `MAX_GRANT_PERCENT` (конкретно эта в 2014 по крайней мере SP2-CU4 действует). Правда для запроса вида `SELECT * FROM users` эти подсказки эффект вряд ли дадут, т.к. он io-ориентирован, подсказок для ограничения iops пока вроде бы нет. И, да, всё-таки непонятно действительно ли вам это нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать условный порядок, чтобы получить 4 строки по вашим критериям:

```
select *
from Mytable
where Myculomn like "%apple%"
OR Myculomn like "%orange%"
OR Myculomn like "%strawberry%"
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Myculomn like "%apple%" THEN 1
    WHEN Myculomn like "%orange%" THEN 2
    WHEN Myculomn like "%strawberry%" THEN 3
    ELSE 4 END ASC
LIMIT
```